# Send a contact to CiviCRM only if the user check a specific checkbox in a Contact Form 7?

Tags: wordpress, contacts, gdpr

I am aware that there is a [Wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-civicrm-integration/) to "link" Wordpress plugin Contact Form 7 and CiviCRM.

But I wonder if there is a way to send to CiviCRM the data of a user who filled the form ONLY if he/she checks a specific checkbox or acceptance box.

This is fundamental to comply with the GDPR.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you make the checkbox required?  What's the use case for a form with contact data you can't use?

Comment: I can use the data only for the purpose the user is giving me them. Let's make a classic example:

I have a "Contact me" form on my website, which asks for Name, Surname and Email of the user. If the user fills the form to contact me for having some info, I can't use those data to send him/her, for example, a newsletter or a fundraising mailing etc. 

I can do this only if he/she checks a specific checkbox which states "I accept to receive newsletters, updates and fundraising email...I've read and agree to the Privacy Policy..."

It's the core principle of the GDPR.

Comment: Right, so by filling in a 'Contact me' form they are giving you permission to contact them about the specific issue in the contact form and you're going to need to store that contact info to fulfil the request. You can also have checkboxes for them to choose what newsletters etc they want to receive.   The GDPR extension helps with this: https://civicrm.org/extensions/gdpr

Comment: Thank you @Aidan. Sorry for my late reply but I was on vacation.
This helps, but do not solve the issue to send the contact to CiviCMR only if the user checks a specific checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways to approach this, but none of them is standard as the Contact Form 7 Integration plugin only throws data over the line and lets CiviCRM take care of the api.

- First of all, it is well possible that standard Contact Form 7 lets you specify a box that prevents submission of the data? If that is the case then that is the quickest and easiest solution

  - Insert a form in between where you ask permission and only take them to the next one (that sends data to CiviCRM) once they have ticked the box
- Adapt the plugin in your installation to NOT send the api call if a certain box is ticked. That would not be an option I would take as I would prefer the next alternative, but is possible.
- Send the data, including the "permission" box, to CiviCRM but use a specifically developed API (something like OkContact create). The check to only create the contact if the box is  ticked is then solved in this API, and the contact is only added if the box is ticked.

Does that help?

Comment: It helps a lot. Unfortunately it goes a little beyond my own skills. But now I have very clear in my mind what I need to overcome this.

Expecially the third and fourth options are very likely to be used in my case.

Thank you again. I will keep you poste.